# How can I get the url of a file on documentum to open it via .net application?

Tags: domdocument

I am trying to provide checkin,checkout and inline editing function for  documents on documentum via .net application.I want to get the url for file to open it via .net application.Is there any direct api or we need to separately write code for this?.(Is it possible to get url of the file by just using the objectid?)

Answer (score -1):

Try to consume documentum DFS webservices to get documents from .NET application.
Please check below urls

https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-2214

https://community.emc.com/thread/83150?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: please answer the question rather than providing links to the documentation